# git --version command not working on VS code

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I am starting with Git and the comand line, when trying to see my GIT version with git --version command, it does not work on VS code, but it does in CMD windows terminal. What is wrong with VS code terminal?

VS code message

PS C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\Proyectos Fokerson> git --version
Error al ejecutar el programa 'git.exe': Acceso denegadoEn
línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- git --version
- 

En línea: 1 Carácter: 1

- git --version
- ```
     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], 
     ApplicationFailedException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
  ```

---

CMD message

C:\Users\Nico>git --version
git version 2.34.1.windows.1

Tried moving directories on VScode with cd.. but not working

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and it was the good old home remedy of rebooting my machine.

Hope that helps.